# Is there a specific terminology to describe a non refreshing background?

Tags: terminology

I was looking for an explanation to why this is occurring to a Windows 10 64 bit machine. But I could not find any result as I don't know what is the name of this effect, the terms I used were too general. So I only found this 1 result. (I know it's not Windows)

What is the term that describes this effect, if any?

Bonus question: Why is this still occurring even when I have a top of the line GPU?

[image]

Comment: This happens when you win!

Comment: I think the words you are looking for are "screen not redrawing"

Comment: The problem could be driver related - Windows farming off screen redrawing to GPU which is then not doing it.

Comment: I think Ghosting is the correct term.